# How to use the Apache HttpClient to make a RESTful call?

Tags: apache, rest, httpclient

I want to ask a question about the Apache HttpClient and RESTful call. I want to use the Apache HttpClient to make a RESTful call. But I don't know how to use it. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: question is not really useful

Comment: @Neema, useful or not depends on who, it just not for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST is basically just HTTP. So, are you saying you don't know how to use HttpClient? Have you read the documentation? HttpClient is [well documented](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), with a straightforward [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) a bunch of [examples](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/).

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have read the document and I want some example class, your answer is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Andre Caron, thank you. Just for the time limitation, cannot accept the answer yet. Finish it.